# Can we create image of text

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to create UIImage of text.Is there any tutorial of something which could help me.I read many blog but all the blogs showing that how to create text on uiimage but I need uimage of written text. If somebody have any idea about this , please help me.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

hi you try this this....
i hope it  will work for you

```
-(UIImage *)imageFromText:(NSString *)text withImage:(UIImage*)img{
   // set the font type and size
   UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:100.0];  
   CGSize size  = [text sizeWithFont:font];

   // check if UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions is available (iOS is 4.0+)
   if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL)
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size,NO,0.0);
   else
       // iOS is < 4.0 
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

   // optional: add a shadow, to avoid clipping the shadow you should make the context size bigger 
   //
   CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   CGContextSetShadowWithColor(ctx, CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0), 5.0, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
   CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx,kCGBlendModeNormal);
//   CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img].CGColor);


   /*NSLog(@"Rect  %@",CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(ctx));
    CGImageRef alphaMask = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    CGContextClipToMask(ctx, CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(ctx), alphaMask);*/


   // draw in context, you can use also drawInRect:withFont:
   [text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) withFont:font];

   // transfer image
   UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    

   return image;
}
```

the method call will be...

```
[self imageFromText:@"Booooooooom"];
```

Comment: Thanks it's working. But It will pixel rate when we resize this image.Do have any solution for that?

Comment: [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[ self resizedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"donald-duck1.jpg"] withSize:CGSizeMake(320, 480) transform:CGAffineTransformIdentity drawTransposed:NO interpolationQuality:1.0]];

Comment: for aspect ratio as fit u want means use this code...
[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[ self resizedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"donald-duck1.jpg"] withSize:CGSizeMake(320, 480) transform:CGAffineTransformIdentity drawTransposed:YES interpolationQuality:1.0]];

Comment: these are the resizing examples you can try this resized image as input of the img

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet of code, should work. You can freely change some of the parameters within function. Note that you must pass UIImage created somewhere else to this method.

```
//Add text to UIImage
-(UIImage *)addText:(UIImage *)img text:(NSString *)text1{
    int w = img.size.width;
    int h = img.size.height; 
    //lon = h - lon;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), img.CGImage);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1);

    char* text  = (char *)[text1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];// "05/05/09";
    CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial", 18, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255, 255, 255, 1);


    //rotate text
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( -M_PI/4 ));

    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 4, 52, text, strlen(text));


    CGImageRef imageMasked = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageMasked];
}
```